# XML String index out of range

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
string Str = "<String><MoreString>";
int Start = Str.LastIndexOf('<') + 1;
int End = Str.IndexOf('>', Start);
string S = Str.Substring(Start, End);
```

If Str is just `"<String>"`, then it works fine, but if Str is `"<String><MoreString>"`, then it throws an index out of range error. Is it because of the "<",">" characters?

Comment: Why don't you use the `Split` method instead?

Comment: @Bond In the debugger everything looks fine, the End index is in the bounds of Str, so it shouldn't throw any errors, but it does.

Comment: @Bond: I agree with you and like to add: "learn to use msdn, visual studio help, google, ..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) doesn't work like this.

Example :

```
String myString = "abc";
bool test1 = myString.Substring(2, 1).Equals("c"); // This is true.
```

The second argument is the number of characters you're going to select, so you should do :

```
string S = Str.Substring(Start, End-Start);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see when you hover over the `Str.Substring` function you see that the second argument of this function is `length`

This will work

```
string Str = "<String><MoreString>";
int Start = Str.LastIndexOf('<') + 1;
int End = Str.IndexOf('>', Start);
string S = Str.Substring(Start, End - Start);
```